# Is it possible to save/modify a post without calling the "save_post" action hook?

Tags: hooks, save-post

There is a [save_post](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook that is run when you save a post. In fact, revisions and autosaves also call this hook. Even if you simply change the status from published to draft it triggers the `save_post` hook.

Is there any way (using normal wp methods) that a post [could be modified](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_publish_post/) without calling `save_post`? (like editing custom fields)

I'm wondering if I need to tie into `transition_post_status` or `updated_postmeta` or if `save_post` is enough.

Comment: Please clarify what you are actually trying to do. From your comment to an answer here, I understand that there is some misunderstanding.

Comment: @kaiser, there is no misunderstanding, Johannes answered the question.

Comment: Sure there was one: I misunderstood that it wasn't the solution :)

Comment: I linked to a codex article of a core function, when the OP meant a (yet another) action hook (run within said function), @Vienna.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: No, you can use [`save_post`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/). Unless you consider programmatic modification of *only* metadata "modifying a post".

---

There (theoretically) is a way of modifying a post without triggering the [`save_post`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) action hook: Direct modification of the database.

But for one no plugin or theme author in his right mind would go that route and for another it would circumvent all other possible action hooks as well.

The other hooks you mention are for entirely different use-cases:
[`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta) or `updated_postmeta` run only when metadata is changed, i.e. not when only title or content are edited.
[`transition_post_status`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) will not run when a published post is merely edited.

*Iff* you consider programmatic updates of post metadata a modification of the post itself you will indeed have to tie into the [`update_post_meta` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta) or the like as well. The [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function calls [`update_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata) ([source on trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L141)) which will run several action hooks (see linked source), but indeed not [`save_post`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/).

Comment: I meant the [transition_post_status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) hook, not the function.

Comment: Removed the possibly misleading link. Added yours.